# JPA: Create JSON object from Query result of multiple rows

Tags: java, json, jpa, dto

Is it possible to create a custom JSON result from a query that returns multiple rows?

**Repository**

```
@Query("SELECT new DTO.KaytDto(d.id, e.name) "
            + "FROM Session e INNER JOIN e.users d WHERE d.id=999")
```

Now this of course prints JSON object array which contains as many objects as there are rows in the database:

```
[{"id":999,"name":John"},
{"id":999,"name":Peter"}]
```

Is it possible to transform this to the following JSON Object format:

```
[{
    "Names": {
        "name": ["John", "Peter"]
    }
}]
```

**DTO Class**

```
public class KaytDto {
    
    private Long Id;
    private String name;

    public KaytDto(Long Id, String name) {
        this.Id = Id;
        this.name = name;

    }

//setters/getters

  @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "KaytDto [name=" + name + ", id=" + Id + "]";
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert native (join) queries in jpa (Hibernate) to json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51854878/convert-native-join-queries-in-jpa-hibernate-to-json)

Comment: @curiosa not quite. I have the DTO but I dont know how to "serialize" it to the JSON format I want. Also the tutorial URL presented looks very confusing.

Comment: Are you, in all seriousness, asking how to convert a list of objects with a `String` property to one object with a `List<String>` property?

Comment: I'm asking should I pass a Set of user Entities in the query to DTO, or is there a more formal way of.. forming the JSON.